# How to repeat a background texture in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a small game in android with libgdx. I have given background as an actor and i added scrolling effect. I want to repeat the image in the background.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is called "parallax background". In the libgdx forums there is a [thread](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=1795) with two classes which support several layers and different scrolling speeds.

Furthermore there is a [test](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ParallaxTest.java) which uses a different approach, modifying a camera.

I think the first classes are the more clean way to do it. I use it myself and it works pretty well.